# Filter by includes and then sort by startsWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, typescript

I'm implementing a `typeahead` where we need to filter for the records where it should begin(sort) the results with `StartsWith` and then `includes`.

Sample Data:

```
Dotnet Developer  
Azure Administrator  
Microsoft Azure  
Azure DevOps  
UX Developer  
IOT Azure
```

If I start typing `Azu`, then it should show the results in the below order.

- **Azu**re Administrator
- **Azu**re DevOps
- Microsoft **Azu**re
- IOT **Azu**re

which means, we are looking for the results which startswith logic and then includes logic.

I have tried the below way but that didn't work, can anyone please guide me on this?

```
abc.filter(v => v.includes(filterTerm)).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.startsWith(filterTerm)
});
```

Also attaching [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw79sa3v/1/) with some sample data.

Comment: you should return a number to the sort function, not a boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work:

```js
const search = (filterTerm, terms) => {
    filterTerm = filterTerm.toLowerCase();
    return terms
        .filter(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(filterTerm))
        .sort((a, b) => {
            const aStarts = a.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterTerm);
            const bStarts = b.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterTerm);
            if (aStarts && bStarts) return a.localeCompare(b);
            if (aStarts && !bStarts) return -1;
            if (!aStarts && bStarts) return 1;
            return a.localeCompare(b);
        });
};

console.log(search("azu", [
    "IOT Azure",
    "Dotnet Developer",
    "Microsoft Azure",
    "Azure DevOps",
    "UX Developer",
    "Azure Administrator",
]));
```

---

If your list of terms is predefined and fixed, but the searching happens frequently, you can streamline the function for re-use:

```
const search = terms => filterTerm => {
    filterTerm = filterTerm.toLowerCase();
    return terms
        .filter(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(filterTerm))
        .sort((a, b) => {
            const aStarts = a.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterTerm);
            const bStarts = b.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterTerm);
            if (aStarts && bStarts) return a.localeCompare(b);
            if (aStarts && !bStarts) return -1;
            if (!aStarts && bStarts) return 1;
            return a.localeCompare(b);
        });
};

const programmingTerms = search([
    "IOT Azure",
    "Dotnet Developer",
    "Microsoft Azure",
    "Azure DevOps",
    "UX Developer",
    "Azure Administrator",
]);
```

Usage:

```
programmingTerms("Azu");  // -> ["Azure Administrator", "Azure DevOps", "IOT Azure", "Microsoft Azure"]
programmingTerms("Dev");  // -> ["Azure DevOps", "Dotnet Developer", "UX Developer"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just sort the list ahead of time. Now, all you need is a debounce for your `input` event and a regular expression to highlight matches in the results.

```js
const data = `
  Dotnet Developer  
  Azure Administrator  
  Microsoft Azure  
  Azure DevOps  
  UX Developer  
  IOT Azure 
`.trim().split('\n').map(line => line.trim()).sort();

// https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/javascript/debounce/
const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
  let timeoutId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
      callback.apply(null, args);
    }, wait);
  };
}

const emptyEl = (el) => {
  while (el.firstChild) el.firstChild.remove();
};

const renderResults = (target, term, hits) => {
  emptyEl(target);
  if (term.length > 0 && hits.length > 0) {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${term})`, 'i');
    const listEl = document.createElement('ul');
    hits.forEach(hit => {
      const listItemEl = document.createElement('li');
      listItemEl.innerHTML = hit.replace(regex, '<strong>$1</strong>');
      listEl.append(listItemEl);
    });
    target.append(listEl);
  } else {
    const emptyEl = document.createElement('p');
    emptyEl.textContent = 'No Results...';
    target.append(emptyEl);
  }
}

const onSearch = debounce((e) => {
  const term = e.target.value.trim();
  const results = document.querySelector('.results');
  const hits = data.filter(text => text.includes(term));
  renderResults(results, term, hits);
}, 250);

document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('input', onSearch);
```

```css
strong { font-weight: bold; color: green; }
```

```html
<input type="search" class="search" placeholder="Search..." />
<h2>Results</h2>
<div class="results">
  <p>No Results...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tweaked the sorting function and it works now. You need to give a number to the sort function.

```js
var abc = ['test', 'test 123', 'test 234', 'abc', 'abc 123', 'xyz', '123', '1235'];
var filterTerm = '123';

var includesList = abc.filter(v => v.includes(filterTerm));

var sortedList = includesList.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.indexOf(filterTerm) < b.indexOf(filterTerm) ? -1 : 1;
});

console.log(sortedList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate a score (0 or 1) which represents the priority of the result, and use it to sort like this:

```js
const abc = [
  "Dotnet Developer (should not appear)",
  "Azure Administrator (should be first)",
  "Microsoft Azure (should be second)",
  "Azure DevOps (should be first)",
  "UX Developer (should not appear)",
  "IOT Azure (should be second)",
];

const filterTerm = "Azu";

const score = searched => string => string.startsWith(searched) ? 1 : 0;

const result = abc.filter(v => v.includes(filterTerm)).sort((a, b) => {
  const [aScore, bScore] = [a, b].map(score(filterTerm));
  return bScore - aScore;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom sort like this. I am returning 1 when `b` starts with your preferred string. When 1 is returned then b is put in front of a.

```js
var abc = ['test', 'test 123', 'test 234', 'abc', 'abc 123', 'xyz', '123', '1235'];
var filterTerm = '123';

var includesList = abc.filter(v => v.includes(filterTerm));

var sortedList = abc.filter(v => v.includes(filterTerm)).sort(function(a, b) {
  if(b.startsWith(filterTerm)) return 1;
  return -1;
});

console.log(sortedList);
```

Comment: A sort function should never use only one of the two parameters

Comment: Oh. Any specific reason for this?

Comment: Because the order of the items in every "group" may depend on the browser's implementation of `Array.prototype.sort`